# NO_COOR reads not in a single block at the end 0 -1

Tags: rna-seq, samtools

I am doing an RNA seq analysis with mouse samples. I had my reads in several lanes, so I concatenated those fastq reads. Then I've mapped my reads with Hisat2 against the new version of mouse  "GCA_000001635.9_GRCm39_genomic.fna".

Apparently everything works well up to here. Now I'm using samtools 1.9 to convert sam to bam, to sort those bam and create the index, just like this:

```
samtools view -bS ${file} > ${file}.bam

samtools sort -n ${file} -o ${file}_sorted.bam

samtools index  ${file}_sorted.bam
```

But when indexing I get this error:

> [bam_sort_core] merging from 11 files and 1 in-memory blocks...
> [E::hts_idx_push] NO_COOR reads not in a single block at the end 0 -1
> samtools index: failed to create index for
> "CD4_1A_concat.bam_sorted.bam": No such file or directory
>
> [bam_sort_core] merging from 11 files and 1 in-memory blocks...
> [E::hts_idx_push] NO_COOR reads not in a single block at the end 23 -1
> samtools index: failed to create index for
> "CD4_1B_concat.bam_sorted.bam": No such file or directory
> [bam_sort_core] merging from 11 files and 1 in-memory blocks...

And more...

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a duplicate of [Samtools Index: Chromosome Blocks not Continuous](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/13997/samtools-index-chromosome-blocks-not-continuous) but with different error messages, and a duplicate of [Error given while trying to index a BAM file with Samtools Index - NO COOR?](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/5352/error-given-while-trying-to-index-a-bam-file-with-samtools-index-no-coor).

```
samtools sort -n ${file} -o ${file}_sorted.bam
```

These error messages also indicate that the reads are not sorted by coordinate — in particular, that the unplaced unmapped reads with RNAME `*` are not all together at the end of the file.

This is because `samtools sort -n` has been used to sort the reads by name instead. Remove `-n` to sort by position, which is what is needed to prepare a BAM file for indexing with `samtools index`.

Comment: Thank you! problem solved :)